# POST with jersey

Tags: java, post, jersey, webserver

I use this code to make POST with jersey

```
@POST
    @Path("/postage")
    public Response postStrMsg( @PathParam("age") String msg) {
        String output = "Age : " + msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
```

And I use a firefox plugin RestCleint to test it. I am not able to get the age parameter but I get the hole POST as a String. For exemple if I test the service with this Body `age=34&test=test` I get the result `POST:Jersey say : age=343&test=test` where I am supposed to get only `34`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `@QueryParam` annotation rather than the `@PathParam` annotation. At least, I assume that what you mean when you say you have a Body 'age=34&test=test' is that the full URI looks like 'http:///postage?age=34&test=test'. `@QueryParam` extracts query parameters from the request URI, while `@PathParam` extracts elements of the path section of the request URI.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html